# CursorAdapter: when i use changeCursor() the event setOnItemClickListener() begin to crash

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I'm updating a ListView that is linked with a CursorAdapter that i have extended.

When I get a notification I upgrade the appropriate table sqlite. Then recover all records from the table with the curosor and use `changeCursor()` to change the ListView.

Unfortunately, the event `setOnItemClickListener` starts to crash maybe **because he uses an old reference to a cursor**.

The following code is executed at the end of an AsyncTask (called by the Activity X) that save data to the table sqlite and set the cursor to the listview. At the end add an event to the listview.

```
final Cursor cursor = dao.getAllRubrica();
        dao.close();

        CustomCursorAdapter provaAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(applicationContext,cursor,0);
        //cursor.close();

        ListView rubricaListView = (ListView) controlPanelActivity.findViewById(R.id.rubricaListView);


        rubricaListView.setAdapter(provaAdapter);
        controlPanelActivity.setRubricaListView(rubricaListView);

        rubricaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String target_email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RUBRICA_DESTINATARIO));

                String userEmail = controlPanelActivity.loadSharPrefs();
                if(userEmail!=null && !userEmail.isEmpty()){
                    // ....
                }
            }
        });
```

The following code is executed when the Activity X receives a notification, so i get the cursor of the listview and change with the new cursor. Now the event setOnItemClickListener begin to crash!

```
CustomCursorAdapter a = (CustomCursorAdapter) rubricaListView.getAdapter();
    a.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

Here the error (the first lines are important):

```
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, destinatario, inizio_conversazione, nick_dest, flag_new_mess FROM rubrica 02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672): at Android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55) 02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
```

02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:213)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.app.task.GetRubricaTask$1.onItemClick(GetRubricaTask.java:211)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-03 14:54:48.791: E/AndroidRuntime(1672):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**How can I continue to run the event after the call to `changeCursor()`? I need to change something in the AsyncTask?**

Comment: plz add log with question if it's crashing

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
            // if it cannot seek to that position.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {
                //Do something with cursor
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, destinatario, inizio_conversazione,
>   nick_dest, flag_new_mess FROM rubrica

This code means you close the database before cursor can retrieve all the data from it, so comment out this line and it will work fine:

```
dao.close();
```

Instead close connection of the cursor and database in either onDestroy or onStop and respectively open again in onCreate or onRestart.
ListView gets data from the adapters in segments to minimize the load on resources, they request data from the cursor when you user scroll down the list, so try to close the database and the cursor at the very end of the life cycle of your activity.